# Unable to parse JSON of crypted text

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I updated to Ruby 2.4.2 which required me to update Gibberish to 2.0.

I am getting this error and not sure what is the culprit.

```
        Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 157ms 
    Feb 20 10:34:14 my-staging app/web.1: ActionView::Template::Error (Unable to parse JSON of crypted text): 
    348:           <% end %> 
    349:           <li class="dropdown <%= 'active' if request.fullpath == "/es/account" %>"> 
    350:             <a aria-haspopup="true"> 
    351:               <i class="icon-user"></i> <%= current_user.email %> 
    352:               <b class="caret"></b> 
    353:             </a> 
    354:             <ul> 
    Feb 20 10:34:14 my-staging app/web.1:   config/initializers/mongoid_encryption.rb:15:in `decrypt'
```

I think the issue might be this gem, but not sure??

```
gem 'mongoid-encrypted-fields', :path => "./vendor/plugins/mongoid-encrypted-fields-1.2.2"
```

Comment: Nothing in that snippet shows what caused the problem. Your module's version isn't tied to Ruby's version, either, so that upgrade could be rolled back if it's problematic.

Comment: Can't be rolled back. I am being forced to move to Ruby 2.4 as MLab is forcing upgrades to mongodb 3.4 from 3.2 and ruby needs to be 2.4

Comment: Might as well bump to Ruby 2.6.1 if you can as that's the current release. As to this problem, it seems dependency related, possibly, but you'll need to identify what line of code is causing the problem.

Comment: Looks like the major issue is Devise. We are on 3.5.2 but bumping up Ruby it wants us to use 4.0.  I see some issues around to many params coming. It says it wants 0 params, but is getting 1 param.  I have searched for almost an hour and cannot find anything show the differences between Devise 3.5 and 4.0?